# Problem with output of Proximus algorithm in R

Tags: r, clustering, binary-data

I have question about output of `PROXIMUS` algorithm. In the example of
use [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Mining_Algorithms_In_R/Clustering/Proximus#Algorithm).
In Case Study section is all clear, but I do not know what way they use
for get clustered words to groups:

```
Group 1 (computers) = {intel, computer, software, linux, windows, Firefox, explorer, programming}
Group 2 (authors) = {kuth, shakespeare, grisham, asimov, book} 
Group 3 (noise) = {love}
```

How can I get this output for my data?

Next in
the example section is graph. How do I read this graph?

My data are:

```
objects cat1    cat2    cat3    cat4 ...
A       TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
B       TRUE    FALSE   TRUE    FALSE
C       TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
D       FALSE   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
E       TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
F       TRUE    FALSE   TRUE    FALSE
```

After apply of `Proximus` algorithm I get this output:

```
pr <- proximus(x, max.radius=8, debug=TRUE)
#Non-Zero: 55
#Sparsity: 0.48
#  0 [6,3,5] 1 >
#  1 [3,3,5] 1 * 1
#  1 [3,1,0] 1 >
#  2 [1,1,0] 1 * 2
#  2 [2,1,0] 1 >
#  3 [1,1,0] 1 * 3
#  3 [1,1,0] 1 * 4


summary(pr)
#Size Length Radius Error Fnorm Jsim Valid
#1    3     16      5  0.16     3 0.81  TRUE
#2    1      9      0  0.00     0 1.00  TRUE
#3    1      4      0  0.00     0 1.00  TRUE
#4    1      2      0  0.00     0 1.00  TRUE
```

So it means that 3 objects are in one cluster and all other objects have
own cluster. What way I can use for get list of objects in cluster? And I get this: [image: graph]

How do I read this graph?

Many thanks for your help!